# Snowflake - Get the schema owner of the currently executing stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, procedure

Is there any way to get the owner schema for a stored procedure from within the executing procedure? For example, I have procedure declared as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UTIL.P_TEST()
EXECUTE AS CALLER
```

When I execute the procedure from within a different schema "NOT_UTIL":

```
USE NOT_UTIL;
CALL UTIL.P_TEST();
```

If I use the CURRENT_SCHEMA() function, I get the name of the schema for the current session "NOT_UTIL" (as-expected), What I need is to get the owner schema for the procedure: UTIL.

In TSQL, we can get the schema using this syntax:

```
OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID)
```

Is there any way to get this value from within a snowflake procedure? Please note that using the "EXECUTE AS OWNER" option is not a viable solution for this use-case.

Answer (score 1):

SET CATALOGUE =(SELECT PROCEDURE_CATALOG FROM SNOWFLAKE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCEDURES  WHERE PROCEDURE_NAME LIKE '%NAME%');

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but this will not help. First of all, your query returns the name of Database the Procedure is in, not the Schema (the correct column is PROCEDURE_SCHEMA);  Second, if there are procedures in multiple schemas with the same name, this will return all of the procedures, not the executing procedure.

Answer (score 0):

`CURRENT_SCHEMA()` will return the value you are looking for, as long as the procedure has `execute as owner` (the default).

Otherwise with `execute as caller` it only knows about the caller's schema.

You didn't specify that you are not using the default `execute as` env in the question, so I'll assume you did, and that the desired result is exactly what you wanted.

Test with:

```js
create schema temp2;
use schema temp.public;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE temp.temp2.currschema()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
-- execute as caller
execute as owner
AS
$$
var cmd = "select current_schemas()";
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
          {
          sqlText: cmd
          }
          );
var result1 = stmt.execute();
result1.next();
return result1.getColumnValue(1);
$$
;

call temp.temp2.currschema();
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-rights.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This does solve the problem if we were able to use "EXECUTE AS OWNER", unfortunately we need to use the "AS CALLER" option. I should have included that in my original question ;) I updated the question to include the additional detail.

Comment: Thoughts: Can you include the schema as hardcoded when you CREATE FUNCTION?

Comment: @hoffa Yes we can hard code the value, but we are trying to find a way to avoid that path if possible.